# System call access in Assembly language

Tags: assembly, system-calls

I want make system call (on linux) in Assembly.
I have problem with system call access. In C code I write:

```
int r= syscall(SYS_access,"file", R_OK);
if(r==0){
printf("Can read\n"); 
}
```

This in C work, but I don't know how can handle with flags and check return. Here is my code:

```
mov eax, 33 ;system call for access
mov ebx, namefile
mov ecx, 0 ;here is int - flag?
int 80h 
cmp eax,0 ;cmp return?
je .YES

.YES:
mov eax,4 ;write
mov ebx,1 ;terminal
mov ecx,yes ;what I write
mov edx,9 ;4
int 0x80 ;call kernel
```

How can I fix flag and compare return?

Comment: It's just a matter of using a search engine. If you google for "man access" you'll find what `access` returns in case of success, and if you google for "#define R_OK" you'll find which value `R_OK` corresponds to.

Comment: If you know how to write it in C, then just compile the C code and look at the resulting machine code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is access functions:

```
#define F_OK        0   /* test for existence of file */
#define X_OK        0x01    /* test for execute or search permission */
#define W_OK        0x02    /* test for write permission */
#define R_OK        0x04    /* test for read permission */
```

Care, this is Hex-code, but hex work too. 
Return values for most system calls it is in EAX, but not for all. A good rule of thumb, when working with a system call for the first time, is to look for the return value in EAX. If it is not there, you need further research.

Access return in EAX.
And check your file. If you in right working directory and if you write correct file name.(your EBX)